# Running Big endian process on little endian cortex A

Tags: arm, endianness, cortex-a

Suppose i am running on Cortex-A53(ARMv8) on Ubuntu.
Cortex-A53 is using little little-endian architecture, is it possible to compile a program as a big-endian and run it on the little-endian system?

Thank!,
Michael

Comment: Not sure, but unlikely. However, almost any (user-space) application can be written in a way such that it is completely endian-agnostic, i.e. works regardless of endianness. In C and C++, typical endian-related problems can be solved by using bitwise operations properly and avoiding certain memory-access constructs (*some* usages of `union`, pointer-casts and `memcpy`).

Comment: I don't understand the question: you compile a software for a given MPU or MCU. One of the characteristics of the target is the endianness but there are many more. So why would you want to compile as big-endian on a little-endian processor ?

Comment: for aarch32 I dont think compile but you could probably run some code and use the setend I think it is instruction on all entry and exit points, but also understand after armv4 or armv5 it switched to byte invariant instead of word invariant.  Cant imagine why you would want to run anything big endian on this processor so the real question is what is the problem you are trying to solve.  if you think you are going to gain some performance working on some big endian data, think again, even if it were word invariant.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean some ARM processors such as the Cortex-A53 support switching between Little Endian and Big Endian at runtume. On AArch64 (i.e. 64bit code), this can be configured via the `SCTLR_EL1.E0E` bit, which I think is only accessible for privileged (kernel) code.

Comment: @Erlkoenig thank you for this precision, I thought the choice of endianness was always done at design level. What is the use case for that ?

Comment: The implementation can also fix the endianness (at design time), but the Cortex-A53 doesn't do that, keeping it configurable at runtime. Use case - perhaps to set it once at boot to run BE/LE OS.